# Gson null deserialization

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to make a java program that will need to work with json, I have choose gson as my library to handle managing JSON

But when I try to deserialize my json the messagereturn.text value and the extra.text value both get set as null, I have tried to fix this but I am unable to.

An example of the json that i am trying to deserialize is

```
{
    "text":"",
    "extra":[{
        "text":"eee joined the game",
        "color":"yellow"
    }]
}
```

And this is how I am calling gson

```
 Message messagepacket = event.<ServerChatPacket>getPacket().getMessage();
                    Messagereturn mr = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(messagepacket), Messagereturn.class);

                    System.out.println(mr.returnmethod());
```

Here is the classes I am trying to deserialize too

messagereturn.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Messagereturn {

    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("extra")
    @Expose
    private List<Extra> extra = null;


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public List<Extra> getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }

    public void setExtra(List<Extra> extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public String returnmethod() {
        Extra extra = new Extra();
       return getText() + extra.getText();
    }
}
```

Extra.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Extra {

    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("color")
    @Expose
    private String color;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error: `String.valueOf(…)` returns the value of toString-method. Since you didn't override it, Gson is called to parse an object reference as JSON – this is wrong. Instead the class Message ought to return the payload itself. This could be an array of bytes or already a String. The latter is better so you don't run into character set issues. Maybe it should look like this:

```
Message messagepacket = event.<ServerChatPacket>getPacket().getMessage();
// or if getPayload is byte[] wrap in new String(messagepacket.getPayload());
Messagereturn mr = new Gson().fromJson(messagepacket.getPayload()), Messagereturn.class);
```

The second error is our method `public String returnmethod()`. The code creates a new instance of Extra with all attributes initialized according to Java Language Specification. In your case: all are null.

I assume instead you meant:

```
public String renderTextAndExtra() {
  if (extra==null || extra.isEmpty()) {
    return text;
  }
  return text+"; all extras="+extra.stream()  // treat all instances
    .map(extra->extra.getText()+";"+extra.getColor())  // turn into String
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // join all Extra Strings by comma
}
```